# Port 8443 running on http not https

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, tomcat9

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am making my first attempt (feels like a hundred) at *installing SSL onto Tomcat9 using Let's Encrypt* and started strong (at least I believe so) and then fell into an infinite loop of not being able to solve a problem. So here I am pleading with more experienced people in hopes of finding a solution to my problem.

In the final steps of my SSL installation I went to check if it was working at `[https://ex.example.com:8443]` however I received the following error: `[ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR]`. I researched this for a while online and found someone on a forum said their site was working on http but not https, so I attempted to see if it was the same on my website. I entered the URL `[http://ex.example.com:8443]` and it worked! I thought it would be clear sailing from here as surely I would be able to find a simple solution to this online however, at my dismay that wasn't the case. I found a result from 9 years ago where someone added a few things to his `<connector>` in his `server.xml` to resolve a similar issue. I tried to do the same but my Tomcat kept crashing when I tried to start it so I narrowed it down to the following: `sslProtocol="TLS"`. I also found someone else edited their `web.xml` to redirect everything to https (except a few things) so I added that (can be found below). I did a few more hours of Googling and here I am now asking anyone who may have an idea of what I should do for assistance.

### server.xml

```xml
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https">

      <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateFile="conf/cert.pem"
                     certificateKeyFile="conf/privkey.pem"
                     certificateChainFile="conf/chain.pem" />
      </SSLHostConfig>

    </Connector>
```

### web.xml

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPSOrHTTP</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, to configure TLS/SSL on Tomcat 9, all you need to do is modify your server.xml file. The web.xml file, be it the top-level one or the webapp-specific one, is not used to define how to run TLS/SSL. The web.xml file is only there to enforce TLS on certain parts of your app.

Now, let's look at your server.xml file. Tomcat provides a [sample here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) that shows how to configure SSL.

```xml
    <Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

That should be it.

This gives you an overall sample config equal to the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>


  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
   
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

This is simply the default config for Tomcat 9.x trimmed down to the necessary parts.

In your use case, you're using `Http11AprProtocol`. I would simply switch to `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol`.

On an unrelated note, in your web.xml, you choose to expose CSS and images over HTTP (or HTTPS). I wouldn't do that. There's no reason to. It's also bad practice from a security and even an SEO perspective. Make it all CONFIDENTIAL.

Comment: I tried adding what you provided above and it didn't work [ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED]. I also don't understand why you add keystore values when I used lets encrypt (openssl) instead of keystore.

Comment: After further review it seems I already had org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol in my server.xml. You said I was using Http11AprProtocol but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: What do you mean you use Let's Encrypt? What do you think it does? It creates a keypair for you which you need to install

Comment: And that's exactly what your sample does. Now there are different ways to store and manage keys. My example uses the default Java way

Comment: How can I make it run only on http ?

Comment: Just comment out the connector for 8443

Comment: Which connector line you mean ?

Comment: Comment this line out: <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">